# how to insert DOM element just after the div clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've my mark up as

```
<div id="wrap">
   <div class="clickhere"></div>
   <div class="clickhere"></div>
   <div class="clickhere"></div>
   <div class="clickhere"></div>
   <div class="clickhere"></div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to add another `<div class="clickhere"></div>` just after the div clicked using jQuery. I thought of `.append()` or `.prepend()` but it only adds at the last or the first of the parent element (if applied at the parent element).

```
$('.clickhere').click(function(){
   // add <div class="clickhere"></div> just below $(this)
})
```

Comment: You've been on StackOverflow nearly a year and a half and asked **91** other questions. You *really should* be formatting code yourself rather than relying on other people to do it for you. **Please** take a moment to read the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the Ask a Question area, and [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. (There's also a preview box shown under the Ask a Question box where you can preview your question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) for that :)

```
$('<div class="clickhere"></div>').insertAfter(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

And in something approaching POJS:

```
> $('.clickhere').click(function(){

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'clickhere';
  this.parentNode.insertBefore(div, this.nextSibling);

> just below $(this) })
```